# Android Studio getting problem in running AVD(Android Virtual Device)

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have Installed Android Studio in My Laptop. The configuration of my system is 4GB 
RAM ad core i3 processor.

After installing the Android Studio as I have install Android Pie and try to run Android Virtual Device it gives me an Error. I have attached screenshot of it with this message please help me to resolve this problem

Screenshot of the Error:

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Answer (score 0):

try to go Android Virtual Device Manager> create virtual device> choose a device> choose system image> then in emulated performance choose GLES 2.0.

Note: that it depends if this will work on your android studio. just try it.